# Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

In the Ads Manager you can create an ad from an existing post by clicking on "Use Existing Post".  I want to confirm that the same functionality is available through the Marketing API.

The `/act_{ad_account_id}/adcreatives` endpoint has a parameter of `object_type`.  Does the value of `SHARE` create an ad from an existing post?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do use existing post, you should look into `object_story_id` fields in the creative section. This is not documented very clearly. So what you will have to do is, instead of `object_story_spec` send the `object_story_id` which has to be the id of the post to be promoted.